# A plane represented as normal and offset?

Tags: game-engine, computational-geometry, raytracing

I am reading someone else's code and he represents a plane as a normal and offset, but
I am not sure what that offset is. I guess it is distance from world origin to plane center?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most likely it is the "distance" from the world origin to the plane. Not to the "plane center" (what's "plane center"?), but to the plane itself.

I put the word "distance" into quotation marks because it could turn out that your "distance" is not normalized, i.e. it is multiplied by some factor.

The equation of 3D plane, as you probably know, is

```
A*x + B*y + C*z + D = 0
```

where `(A, B, C)` is the normal vector and `D` is actually the *signed* distance from the origin to the plane. However, `D` will represent regular Euclidean distance if and only if vector  `(A, B, C)` is normalized, i.e. the values of `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` are scaled so that `|(A, B, C)| = 1`. If the vector is not normalized, then `D` is the distance multiplied by `|(A, B, C)|`.

Sometimes the term "offset" is used to refer to coefficient `D` in non-normalized plane equation. In other words, it is possible that in your case the plane is simply represented by its `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` coefficients. Whether they are normalized or not - you have to check yourself.

Comment: @user1796942: That's correct. Coefficient `D` will tell you which side of the plane the point `O` (origin) lies on. If it lies on the same side the normal vector `(A, B, C)` is pointing to, `D` is positive. If it lies on the other size, `D` is negative. If `O` lies on the plane, `D` is zero.

Comment: In general, if you take arbitrary point `P(zp, yp, zp)` and calculate `A*xp+B*yp+C*zp+D`, the result will give you *signed* distance from the plane to point `P` (possibly not normalized). The same rules apply: if the distance is positive, point `P` lies on the same side normal vector `(A, B, C)` is directed to and vice versa. If the value is zero, then naturally `P` lies on the plane.

Comment: so is this distance the distance from the world origin to the closest point on the plane?

Comment: @user1796942: Exactly. Coefficient `D` is the shortest "distance" from `O` to the plane. Just remember that it is signed. And it is true Euclidean distance if and only if you have normalized your plane equation, i.e. divided all coefficients by `|(A, B, C)|`.

Comment: I have no experience with this representation of a plane, do you have some links to code for finding ray-plane intersection, where the plane is represented like this?

Comment: @user1796942: This is actually a quite... canonical representation of a plane in 3D. Finding the intersection with a line will depend greatly on how the line is represented. How is your line represented. (You can add this all to the question instead of doing it in the comments).